# LoggedInUserAttribute_<attribute> Jasper Server

Tags: jasperserver

I'm currently using the Jasper Reporting Server and I'm trying to use an input data type to read multiple values from a user assigned attribute.

input data type: LoggedInUserAttribute_location

User Attribute: location
- Value: 1
- Value: 2

---

I've Tried using multiple values within the user attribute:
User Attribute: location
- Value: 1
- Value: 2
**However**, the input data type(LoggedInUserAttribute_) will only read the first one, and the second gets ignored.

my reports will pull information on location = 1
but
location = 2 gets ignored.

Is there a way for the report to use both values?